# URL parameter is ignored when sent with Python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

**First, the code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python'
payload = {'pageSize': '5'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
content = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
questions = soup.select('div#questions h3')

print(r.url)
print(len(questions))
```

**Output**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?pageSize=5
50
```

**Expected Output**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?pageSize=5
5
```

In making the above request, stackoverflow.com appears to be semi-ignoring the pageSize parameter. I say *semi-ignoring*, because r.text does contain '<meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?**pageSize=5**"/>', which indicates that it is aware of the parameter. But it returns 50 questions. If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?pageSize=5 directly, it only returns 5 questions.

Is there a way to get stackoverflow.com to respect the URL parameter sent via http requests?

Comment: Are you querying the web site, but not the stackoverflow API?

Comment: @Rafalsonn, yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was your `User-Agent`, So `requests` headers look like this

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Notice your `User-Agent` it is 'python-requests' So StackOverflow is ignoring the query parameters because it knows it is not coming from a real browser So to overcome this you can simply pass empty headers while making a request like this,

```
requests.get(url, headers='')
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Any idea if it's possible to do with the Requests library?

Comment: I am trying with `requests` will update this answer once i figure out.

Comment: Hey, I updated the answer let me know if this works @Webucator